# Angular 7 HttpClient: ToPromise does not work with put request

Tags: node.js, angular, express, node-modules, put

I'm trying to create an HTTP put request API using express that calls a function upon competition. I successfully got the API calls to update the database but the functions within .then() and .catch() are not being called. Does toPromise() not work for put requests?

On the frontend, I tried adding types to the function and defining it as asynchronous. On the backend, I tried restructuring the .then() and catch() statements. Nothing seems to work.

#### app.component.ts

```
public async save(): Promise<any> {
    return this.httpClient.put<any>('/api/update-account', {
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email
    }).toPromise()
      .then(() => {
        // Run if successful put request
        success()
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // Run if error
        fallback()
  })
}
```

#### server.js

```
app.put('/api/update-account', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name;
    let email = req.body.email;

    sql.connect(dbConfig).then(() => {
        return sql.query`UPDATE users SET Name=${name} WHERE Email=${email}`
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        sql.close();
    })
});
```

I expect success() or fallback() to run after the API request, but neither are being called.

Comment: You aren’t sending back a response in your put, at least in the visible code. So then would potentially never trigger. Try at minimum sending a 200 from the put code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a response using express. For example:

```
return res.status(200).send('My value');
```

Because you don't return a response anywhere, nothing is returned to the client.